# justify this excution please c++

Tags: c++

```
int x = 5, y = 10;
if(x > 0)
    y = y + 100;
else;
    y = y + 200;
cout << "y = " << y << endl;
```

> The output: 310

I know that whenever there is a semicolon after else it is treated as there is nothing. I also know that if there were no curl braces then we only execute the first statement after if.

Then why the answer here appears as the second statement was executed?

Also, if the else was not there will the second be executed also and why?

Comment: I think you left out your sample code.  Could you try posting it?  Then we might be able to help you.

Comment: Because the second statement WAS executed since it was out of the if/else statement.

Comment: `y=y+200` is always executed, no matter what happened before, due to that `;` right after the `else`. Don't get confused because of the identation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: okay another Question if it is possible if the else was not there will the second be executed also and why ? and thank you for your help btw.

Comment: Please don't post images of code. Post the code. I think J-L was hinting at that.

Comment: yeah in the silde it is not a full code so sorry for that but it is posted like this I will try next times to use the code if I posted my own I am new so I apologize.

Comment: You can simply type it out yourself. I did it now for you, but next time, please do it yourself. Images of code (or any text for that matter) are bad for so many reasons, but the most important is accessibility: People who cannot see images are unable to read the text if it's in an image.

Comment: thank you so much I understand now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After an `if` and after an `else` there needs to be exactly one statement. The statement after `if` will be executed if the condition is `true`, the statement after `else` will be executed if the condition is false.

Now the important thing to understand is the following:

1. A single semicolon `;` is a statement. It's an empty statement and putting it behind `if` or behind `else` fullfils the requirements of a statement.
2. A block between curly brackets `{}` is a statement. It groups multiple statements together, but it is one statement and thus also fulfills the requirements.

Any other statement that comes after the first statement after `if` or `else` has nothing to do with the `if` or `else` and will be executed like any other code would.

So to break down your example:

```
if(x > 0)
    y = y + 100;
else;
    y = y + 200;
```

is equivalent to:

```
if(x > 0)
    y = y + 100;  // first statement after if
else
    ;             // first statement after else

y = y + 200;      // separate statement uneffected by if or else
```

Removing the `else` gives us this:

```
if(x > 0)
    y = y + 100;  // first statement after if

y = y + 200;      // separate statement uneffected by if
```

and of course the statement `y = y + 200;` will be executed, because it has nothing to do with the `if` or the `else`.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, both statements will be executed. 
    `if(x>0)` 
is true so the first part will work
    `y = 110`
after this, then we reach else and that is the end of the line the next line does not have anything to do with the if-else block, it will always execute. hence 
    `y = 110 + 200`
, so y will have a final value of 310.

Hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: it helps thanks a lot .